# Detecting if User Exists on the Discord Client (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, detect

I have been trying to detect if a user exists on the Discord Client itself... I used this:

```
var user_id;

//on message and after assigning user_id
if(client.users.cache.get(user_id) !== undefined) {
//checks if user does exist on the client and does action (it always thinks it's undefined for some reason)
}
```

Can you help me? I appreciate all your help...

Thank you,
Rako Games

Comment: Have you tried this: `client.fetch(user_id)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO! Here's how I'd have done that. [`UserManager#Cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) is a collection, so you can use [`Collection#has`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=has) to check if what you're looking for exists. Demo:

```js
const userId = "000000000000000000";
const exists = client.users.cache.has(userId);
console.log(exists); // true or false

// Advice to stop making cringe code --no worries, we've all been there before ;)
if (exists) doSomething(); // And not: if (exists === true), although it still can be used in other places
if (!exists) do SomethingElse(); // And definitely not: if (exists === false)
```

Of course, this will search in the cache, so it won't work if a user never did a thing while your bot was up. To fetch and test if a user exists with [`UserManager#fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserManager?scrollTo=fetch):

```
const exists = await client.users.fetch(userId); // Warning: await here. To be used in async functions, or to be replaced by .then()
// Here, the user is cached
console.log(exists); // undefined or User; can be check as in the snippet above. You can still wrap 'exists' with Boolean() if you feel more comfortable having boolean values
```

Comment: Yea is see it works if I use: if(exists = true){} Thank You!